# How to run custom, non window app in kiosk mode in windows 10

Tags: powershell, windows-10, kiosk, kiosk-mode

I wanted to run some application at start in windows 10, which I did by putting them in startup folder. Now I want to run these apps in kiosk mode, so that user does not see what applications are running at back and he just sees internet browser with some website like google.com. I tried to set up a different local account under kiosk mode, but I am able to run it only with windows app, which are provided under `Add an app`.  Could someone please suggest how to add custom apps in kiosk mode so that I can run my `.exe` files at back at start and screen shows the internet browser?

Answer (score 4):

If you have Windows 10 Enterprise or Education then you can try the Shell Launcher feature to run an exe-application as a shell replacement in kiosk mode.

See https://technet.microsoft.com/itpro/windows/configure/set-up-a-kiosk-for-windows-10-for-desktop-editions#shell-launcher

If not, modify `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell` for the user with your script/application, while locking down the OS (ctrl+alt+delete behaviour etc.) with GPO.

Comment: I tried the website you mentioned, but it says about adding a certificate and installer file for setting up kiosk mode. I have custom .exe program files, which do not have any certificate or installer file

Comment: Replacing explorer.exe is EXACTLY how our kiosk product does this. It works great, because you don't need to worry about the user accidentally getting to the desktop or bringing up the start menu. Control-Alt-Delete and Windows-L are still a problem, and [you should ideally set up autologon](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/324737/how-to-turn-on-automatic-logon-in-windows). Note: You should NOT be replacing the shell for the admin on the machine. You should be creating a new (regular) user, and setting their shell to be the new application.

Comment: @learningpal Certificate and installer path are optional parts when creating a provisioning package. You can skip that and configure it manually by enabling the feature and executing the PowerShell-script (modify and use the parts you need). I've updated the link to take you to the correct section

Comment: As the linked page says, a problem with that solution is that "Apps that run in kiosk mode cannot use copy and paste."