# Virtual keyboard not shown in kiosk mode

Tags: wpf, kiosk-mode, on-screen-keyboard

Wpf application targeting .NET Framework 4.6.2 on Windows 10 Enterprise.
The touch keyboard shows up automatically when a text field gets focus.

The computer station must operate in **kiosk mode** and one way to achieve it is to replace the default shell for the logged in user.

According to [How to run custom, non window app in kiosk mode in windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43400694/how-to-run-custom-non-window-app-in-kiosk-mode-in-windows-10) the following registry key was added: `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell`

Now the application runs in **kiosk mode** but the virtual keyboard is not shown anymore, so it is useless.

Can someone confirm that automatic keyboard introduced in .NET Framework 4.6.2 doesn't work if the application is launched as the default shell ?

In the article [Use Shell Launcher to create a Windows 10 kiosk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-shelllauncher), talking about the shell launcher Version 2 enhancements, it is reported:

> You can use a custom Windows desktop application that can then launch UWP apps, such as Settings and Touch Keyboard.

Is the above keyboard the same one I need ? Following the shell launcher version 2 procedure will the keyboard popup again without rewriting the application code?

Thanks
Filippo

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34769169/open-windows-10-touch-keyboard-docked-in-wpf  Personally, I've built my own keyboard control in the past so I had total control over showing it and what keys were available. It wasn't much work really -  about a day's work to write the usercontrol. This was always visible and filled the bottom of the screen. Moving it around to avoid overlapping stuff would of course be more work.

Comment: @Andy. Very interesting hint to keep the keyboard always visible and don't worry about what it may overlap. Unfortunately I doubt I have the necessary space on the screen.

Comment: Our app was very simple input. Deliberately so.  You'd want work out where the focussed control was and stick the keyboard in an adorner layer. Pick say 4 alternative positions.... and make sure there's always one of them will work with any given input control. Which is do-able but more work.